# Telegram bot status

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-api

I'm wondering if it provides Telegram API the ability to set the status of bots "Online" or "Writes"?

I tried to find information about this on the Internet, but there are no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### No, this is not possible

---

From the [bot introduction page #4](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans):

> 4. How are bots different from humans?
>
>    - **Bots have no online status and no last seen timestamps**, the interface shows the label 'bot' instead.
>    - ...
>    - Bots never eat, sleep or complain (unless expressly programmed otherwise).